# c incomplete element type in array

Tags: c, pthreads

Hi i am working on an assignment in which I need to process some images(resizing) using pthreads.

This is the contents of the filename.h

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    int width;
    int height;
    int max_value;
    int *input;
    int *output;
}image;

typedef struct {
    int id; // thread id
    image *in; //input image
    image *out; // output image
}ptf_arguments;
```

And this is the contents of filename.c file

```
    void resize(image *in, image * out) { 
    int i;
    // printf("Type is %d. We have width = %d and height = %d. Max value is %d\n", in->type, in->width, in->height, in->max_value);
    pthread_t tid[num_threads];
    struct ptf_arguments arguments[num_threads]; // <- HERE
    for(i = 0 ; i < num_threads; i++) {
        arguments[i].id = i;
        arguments[i].in = in;
        arguments[i].out = out;
    }
    printf("First thread should have id = %d. In image of (%d)\n", args[0].id, arguments[0].in.width);
    for(i = 0 ; i < num_threads; i++) {
        //pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, resize_thread_function, &(args[i]));
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
 error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct ptf_arguments’
     struct ptf_arguments arguments[num_threads];
```

at the line marked by the <- HERE comment
the compiling command is :

```
gcc -o filename filname.c -lpthread -Wall -lm
```

What is happening and how can i fix this ? Thank you

EDIT 1: Yes, i did #include "filename.h"

Comment: Your code shown doesn't include the definition of a `struct ptf_arguments` - did you leave it out or should that just be `ptf_arguments` (without the `struct`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `ptf_arguments` is *not* a structure, it's a typename (a type alias). And as a typename it can be used as any other type (like e.g. `int`).

To solve your error, drop the `struct` part of the declaration:

```
ptf_arguments arguments[num_threads]; // <- HERE
```